# Chrome ignores LI class in certain cases

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

Given the following snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            .red {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li id="a">A</li>
            <li id="b">B</li>
        </ul>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#b').addClass('red');
                }, 0);
                $('#a').addClass('red');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

On Chrome produces this output (note the black circle):

[image: 1]

<del>Just swapping the order of the elements or the order of the JavaScript lines solves the problem.</del> **not** true, was something on my production code.

This also exists on Chrome Canary, and works correctly at least in Firefox.

Has anyone experienced this problem? Should this be reported (and where)?

Comment: This is a known bug, cannot just find any reference. Force UI repainting or use pseudo element to display bullet

Comment: thanks, didn't find that question. Should I delete this one?

Comment: @JohnKiller Here's some solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907633/dynamically-changing-the-color-of-an-element-li-doesnt-change-the-color-of-the

Comment: @JohnKiller You could keep it as reference. Maybe future other readers wouldn't have find the other dupe either.  In your case, this would be a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/L9w1nbrr/

Comment: Just wondering, what do you mean here: `Just swapping the order of the elements or the order of the JavaScript lines solves the problem.`?

Comment: In my production code it works by swapping the order of the elements, but you are right: in this simplified example, the problem remains, so it must be something else in my code that refreshes the page.

Comment: @JohnKiller Ya i guess some other code fire some UI repainting