# Bootstrap navbar items controlling container visibility

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap (I'm editing in Bootstrap Studio) I have a navbar that is "fixed to top" and a number of containers that have their visibility toggled using "collapse". I want to be able to click on a navbar item and if the currently open container isn't the one associated with the item, it should close and the clicked on item's associated container should open (and the clicked on menu item should get set to "active").

Here's a sketch of where I'm at; clicking on the navbar items will open and close their own containers but not close any other open containers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand navbar-link" href="#">Vizimetrix Vapor Registry</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#container1" data-toggle="collapse">Container 1</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#container2" data-toggle="collapse">Container 2</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#container3" data-toggle="collapse">Container 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container collapse in" id="container1">
        <div class="row">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container collapse" id="container2">
        <div class="row">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container collapse" id="container3">
        <div class="row">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/menuclose.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just changed the code above as only container1 should have "collapse in"; the other two containers needed to have only "collapse".

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it using jQuery, with your original HTML:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand navbar-link" href="#">Vizimetrix Vapor Registry</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#container1" data-toggle="collapse">Container 1</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#container2" data-toggle="collapse">Container 2</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#container3" data-toggle="collapse">Container 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container collapse in" id="container1">
        <div class="row">
            container 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container collapse" id="container2">
        <div class="row">
            container 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container collapse" id="container3">
        <div class="row">
            container 3
        </div>
    </div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".container").hide();
});

$("ul.nav li").click(function() {
  $("li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});

$("ul.nav li a").click(function() {
  var menu = $(this).attr("href");
  $(".container").hide();
  $(menu).show();
});
```

Updated JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2p1dcosv/4/

...

Also I would suggest putting all the js functionality either on the anchor tag or the LI tag, instead of using both. Right now you have the LI tag toggling the "active" state and the anchor tag's href is what triggers the containers. You could apply all the CSS styling to the anchor tag instead of the LI and then you would only need one click function:

```
$("ul.nav li a").click(function() {
  $("ul.nav li a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var menu = $(this).attr("href");
  $(".container").hide();
  $(menu).show();
});
```

Comment: Here's menuclose.js:  
  
`$(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle' ) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});`

Comment: The purpose of menuclose.js is to close the menu after clicking on an item.

Comment: I just tried your jsfiddle example and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Updated my answer / jsFiddle. Strange my original post worked fine in Safari but I see it wasn't working to change the LI color in Chrome. I think that might be a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907633/dynamically-changing-the-color-of-an-element-li-doesnt-change-the-color-of-the

Comment: Many thanks! You got me going in the right direction.

Comment: No problem. I actually am not using menuclose.js at all in my solution! I missed the part where the menu should toggle when clicking the active link though. That is a bit tricky as you can only toggle classes, not IDs. I tried with classes and that is still tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Nice! But I just found a simple way that works:

```
$("ul.nav li").click(function() { 
  $("li").removeClass("active"); 
  $(this).addClass("active"); 
  $("div.container").removeClass("in") 
});
```

The second to last line simply removes the class "in" from any container and voila! I t appears to work fine but is there any reason not to use this?